# Generating sorted data with test.check

Tags: clojure, test.check

I'd like to use test.check to generate **sorted** time series data of the form

`[ [timestamp value] [timestamp value] ..]`

where the timestamp, value -pairs are in ascending order by the timestamp.

I can easily generate such data in random order with

`(gen/tuple timestamp gen/int)` where `timestamp` is e.g. `(gen/choose 1412664660 1423419720)`

How should I go about generating sorted data?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just `fmap sort` over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it came to me while brushing my teeth..

When I asked the question I was thinking "one level too low" about the data I want to generate.

`(gen/tuple timestamp gen/int)` generates individual tuples and my attempts of doing `(gen/fmap sort .. )` on them didn't work because it just sorted the contents of the tuples. What I need to generate is  vectors of those tuples.. and `fmap sort` on those of course works:

```
(def entry (gen/tuple timestamp gen/int))
(def timeseries (gen/fmap sort (gen/vector entry)))
```